# What version of IE is being used inside Outlook 2016 Desktop app?

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps

I initially assumed it would be the IE that is currently installed but there seems to be some differences. I get JS related errors when loading my add-in Outlook 2016 Desktop but not in Office 365 (Web). How would I find solution to the problem if I do not know which IE is being used to render my add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found also some differences on the IE installed on your computer and the one running you add-in. For example, see the answer from Jeffrey Chen [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c36a1706-e1b8-4d29-96ce-b52fe774c692/what-is-the-recommended-solution-for-implementing-the-oauth-20-flow-in-sandboxed-app-for-office?forum=appsforoffice) he explains that the two IE do not run in the same integrity level (L-level vs M-Level).

I believe you may be interested in using F12 for debugging your add-in iFrame, [see instructions here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).

Comment: Are you aware of any doc that points the out the difference between these integrity levels?

Comment: @Ibrahim sorry I am afraid not. I am not sure it is the only difference by the way.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the version of Internet Explorer used to render the add-in *is* the version of your Internet Explorer.  The only slight exception to this rule is that note that we're talking about IE here, not Edge.  So if you're on Win10, the renderer for the Add-in (at least as of today, end-of-2016) is IE, **not** Edge.

There might be some other issue that's being masked.  Try attaching a debugger when the Add-in runs?  (For instructions on the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168644/678505).

Comment: I tried that from VS but Javascript Console says `Application is not currently attached to a script debug target that supports script diagnostics` and launching DOM Explorer shows nothing.

Comment: Btw, I am running the add-in from Outlook Desktop 2016.

Comment: Let me reach out to some folks on my team who are more familiar with this area.

Comment: Hi Michael! Would the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key be in play here? I know the Outlook Today page depends on this being set to IE 10 (I believe) or earlier so as NOT to use the latest version of IE. Is it using the WebBrowser control or some variant?