# Difficulties debugging add-in

Tags: excel, reactjs, visual-studio, office365, office-addins

I'm using Atom as an editor (I really dislike Visual Studio) to develop an Excel add-in. The project was generated using `yo office`, and I followed the contents of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react) to get started (I'm using React). I added a `console.log` to check the contents of a variable but couldn't find the output, so I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165316/console-log-in-javascript-office-addin), with the suggestion to attach a VS debugger. MS has some documentation on how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane).

However, after doing that, not only do I not see the contents of `console.log`, the Excel file I have open with the add-in sideloaded becomes unresponsive, to the point where I can't even bring it forward if it's behind other applications, or click on it at all. I can't find further explanation on why this is happening or how to fix it.

My questions: How/where can I see the information being logged? And do I need VS to debug, or is there another tool I can use?

EDIT: Looking at the VS debugger on the Output window, it's slowly loading a lot of resources. On the bottom red bar, the word "Ready" flashes inconsistently. If I leave it alone for 5+ minutes it finally finishes loading and Excel becomes responsive again (actually, this happened once. The second time I tried this, Excel stayed unresponsive), but I still don't see the contents of `console.log`

EDIT 2: Sorry for editing this a lot, but I found out that after loading all resources (again, 5+ min), if I click on "Continue" on the top toolbar, Excel becomes responsive and usable again. Still no console.log output though.