# Unable to view `console.log()` output while debugging Excel add-in

Tags: excel, debugging, office365, office-js

I'm attempting to rewrite an add-in that was made back in 2001.  While attempting to do so, I've run into what I can only call "a bit of a snag".  I've been following the Excel API documentation and using Visual Studio 2019.  I'm able to run the add-in just fine.  Hitting run in VS opens up an instance of Excel, side loads the add-in and attaches to the processes to begin debugging.

However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the output from the `console.log()` calls that are in the add-in.  I'm able to get them by using the Microsoft Edge Devtools Preview, but it makes no sense to me why I shouldn't be able to see the output in VS when it's already watching those processes.  I attempted the fixes mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165316/console-log-in-javascript-office-addin) article but came out empty handed.  I've started Excel and the add-in by itself then attached the processes that way, and still no logs.

I've also seen another article that mentions going to something like hitting CTRL+Q and then searching for Javascript Console which comes back with nothing.  I'm really out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript console was removed from Visual Studio 2019. The only workaround that let's you stay in Visual Studio is to install Visual Studio 2017 side-by-side with VS 19. Then do your Excel add-in development with VS 17. If you don't want to do that, then you can continue to Edge DevTools.

Comment: I feel genuinely stupid for not even thinking to try a different VS version.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer me.  Does make me wonder why they removed the console and/or why they didn't allow it to be added back as an extension or something.